# Is chanting without concentration effective?

Tags: practice, vedic-chanting

Sometimes I chant the name of Lord Rama without concentration absentmindedly. Is this form of chanting effective?

Comment: It atleast has some benefits. For eg. See example of Ajamila who pronounced Nãrayana... also in Skandha Purana there is a story where a hunter used to hunt pronouncing prahara... latter it was of great benefit as prahara consists of pra**Hara** ....

Comment: @Tezz welcome to post an answer!